# Azure Data Factory: How to copy specific files based on file's create date?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I failed for below test case:

1. Create new folderA on SourceContainer and insert fileA
2. Trigger Pipelines to copy it to TargetContainer successfully
3. Delete folderA/fileA from TargetContainer
4. Trigger Pipelines with specific start and end time (try to not copy all folders/files again)
5. Cannot see folderA/fileA on TargetContainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Copy activity, source features: you can mention the range of the date of the files which you need to copy:

[image]

And w.r.t trigger a pipeline when file is created, you can use Event trigger to achieve that.